# batch script to change directory and then run kace runkbot 4 0

Tags: batch-file

Hi I am trying to write a batch script to run runkbot 4 0.

So far what I have is:

`start cmd.exe /k "C: && cd \program files\dell\kace\runkbot.exe" -s 4 0`

Everytime I run this I get an error that directory cannot be found.

If I run it like this it finds the directory:

`start cmd.exe /k "C: && cd \program files\dell\kace\`

Can anyone tell me how to open a cmd prompt, change the directory and then run the runkbot 4 0 through a batch script?

Answer (score 0):

`cd` means change directory, but you're giving it a `.exe` file. It can't find the directory named `runbot.exe` because that's not a directory. The first example will work if you just remove the `cd` since the first part of a command is assumed to be executable. `cd` is a known executable, but so it any other `.exe` file you specifically request.

try:

```
start cmd.exe /k "C: && \program files\dell\kace\runkbot.exe" -s 4 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a batch script:

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\program files\dell\kace\"
runkbot.exe -s 4 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

"%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Dell\KACE\runkbot.exe" 4 0
"%PROGRAMFILES%\Dell\KACE\runkbot.exe" 4 0